# kafka streams: publish/send messages even when few record transformation throw exceptions?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

A typical kafka streams application flow is as below (not including all step like props/serdes etc) -

```
    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    final KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream(inputTopic);

    final KStream<String, String> textTransformation_1 = textLines.processValues(value ->  value+"firstTranstormation");  

    final KStream<String, String> textTransformation_2 = textTransformation_1.processValues(value ->  value+"secondTranstormation"); 

    //my concern is at this stage -
    final KStream<String, String> textTransformation_3 = textTransformation_2.processValues(this::processValueAndDoRelatedStuff); 
    
    ....
    ....
    textTransformation_x.to(outputTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
      

    final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfiguration);

    streams.start();

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
```

---

Now if the `processValueAndDoRelatedStuff(String input)` method throws an error, I don't want the program to crash but want `kafka` to only NOT send that one transformation output  to `outputTopic` (i.e ignore the transformation of that one record) and continue dealing with processing rest of the incoming messages normally.

**Is the above possible??**

In generally, as there is a way to skip sending transformation output to `outputTopic` based on a predicate. In the next stage, I can think of adding an filter, if in  `processValueAndDoRelatedStuff(String input)` i can catch the exception and return some value based on which I can filter in the next stage.

```
final KStream<String, String> textTransformation_4 = textTransformation_3.filter((k,v) -> !v.equals("badrecord"));
```

But I am more interested in the case where the exception is not handled but thrown from the mapper functions. Is it possible for kafka to ignore that one record causing an exception and still proceed with rest of processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior is to stop the topology on any *uncaught* exception.

If you want to catch them, simply don't use a function handle. Use a try-catch around the function

```
final KStream<String, String> textTransformation_3 = textTransformation_2.processValues(value -> {
  try {
    return processValueAndDoRelatedStuff(value); 
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // log, if you want
    return null;
  }
).filter((k, v) -> Objects.nonNull(v)); // remove events that caused exceptions
```

Otherwise, you can set exception handlers, as well - https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/error-handling/

Comment: well, the `try` / `catch` approach will work. +1 But I am more interested in `StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler` approach.  How does `StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD` really help. The documentation of this API is quite poor.  Should not there be a `StreamThreadExceptionResponse.CONTINUE` which is my intended case. Could you confirm how `StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD` works or what it does **and** if this fits to my case. And is not restarting a stream thread quite costly, as it has to start over with all the topic connections / consumer group joining etc again.

Comment: Those enums are for catching the exception type, I believe, (i.e. they are a Response type) not denoting the type of handler to use (such as `LogAndContinue`). Your question was simply to not crash, which is the default behavior... The available handler classes are clearly documented in the JavaDoc, IMO

Comment: thanks for involvement - I do understand what `StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD` does. But what I need is `StreamThreadExceptionResponse.CONTINUE` which the api does not provide. The api does support LOG and CONTINUE functionality in other cases through `ProductionExceptionHandlerResponse.CONTINUE` but not for `StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler`.  Like proposed in your answer, at present, try/catch is the only way to deal with if we just want to ignore or act to the exception and continue.

Comment: is it `filter(Objects::nonNull)` or `filter((k, v) -> Objects.nonNull(v))`. The key is still untouched right?

Comment: `nonNull` doesn't accept a tuple, so only the second option should compile